# Error with redis protocol (RESP) during bulk load when data contains UTF-8 characters

Tags: linux, encoding, redis

I have to do simple structured bulk load on my redis database. However there are also some UTF-8 characters and when I'm trying to load in data with them I am getting ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' ' . Loading in data without UTF-8 characters works just fine.

Data example of UTF-8 char that is causing the error :

```
*4\r\n$4\r\nHSET\r\n$6\r\nGrad_Ž\r\n$6\r\nalmada\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n
```

If I replace **Ž** with normal character like **S** for example it loads and causes no errors.

I have tried different commands to run it and I have tried changing bash locale.

Command I am using to run it :

```
echo -e "$(cat test.txt)" | redis-cli --pipe
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

```
$6\r\nGrad_Ž\r\n
```

`6` means that there's 6 bytes value, however, `Grad_Ž` has more than 6 bytes. Because `Ž` is NOT an ascii character, and takes more than 1 byte.

You need to set the correct string length (in byte) for the value.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, script that is generating the protocol needs to be adjusted. Thanks for the answer.